# search in textbox for different fields help is required

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

We have requirement, to search for different fields using a single text box. For example, the search has to be based on three fields; Product, Brand and Place.

Initially the user will be given the below text in the textbox which cannot be modified: `Product:-Brand:-Place`

When user wants to search for Product, Brand and Place, he will just add values: `Product:"TV"-Brand:"Samsung"-Place:"London"`

When user wants to search for just Product: `Product:"TV"-Brand:-Place`

Can some body help me, how can be done that in jQuery or angular js?

Comment: This sounds like a nightmare to maintain. What if someone accidentally changes the format of the single search box, so that `Product` is spelled incorrectly? I would suggest you use three individual boxes for the search values; one for each field to be searched.

Comment: This is the requirement, the user wanted this way. any other suggestion would be great.

Comment: Users aren't always right ;)

Comment: -:) yes, they wanted to have single search box. any other suggestion would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using angular filter..

You can pass an object as the second parameter to achieve this if you can have two search fields

```
<div ng-repeat="friend in user.friends | filter:{name:searchNameText, age:searchAgeText}">
```

Otherwise you'll need to write a custom filter to use the same field for both, or pass a custom filter function as the third parameter which is described in the docs.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter